# Liquidity measures for Commodities Futures

Tags: futures, commodities, liquidity

I would like to find a way to measure Liquidity for Commodities Futures. I found the following 4 papers/definitions:

1. Volume (Share / Dollar) ([Dollar Volume Liquidity](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dollar-volume-liquidity.asp))
2. Amivest Liquidity Ratio ([Comparison of Liquidity Measures in the Stock Markets](http://www.kafo.or.kr/board_common/file_download.asp?Board_Key=233&File_Key=233&flag=1))
3. Amihud: ([The Night and Day of Amihud's (2002) Liquidity Measure by Yashar H. Barardehi, Dan Bernhardt, Thomas Ruchti, Marc Weidenmier :: SSRN](http://%20https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=630093101127025064122114092070015068031053050050057049071106021072103084077103095094028058042052005023061080016011007116010069014012043035035112104104121067024115028095082080068013007087109088114073021077089112088123118104106066087077113072121087113024&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE), [Illiquidity and stock returns:cross-section and time-series effects](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emkearns/finread/amihud.pdf))
4. ([Commodities Liquidity Measurement and Transaction Costs](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41407840?seq=1))

The first 3 only refer to Stocks.

Are the above measures applicable both to Stocks and to Commodities?

Can they be applied to Future Contracts?

Would they be equally valid on daily basis vs a monthly or yearly basis?

Comment: What is your goal in measuring liquidity?

Comment: ADV (average daily volume) and OI (open interest) are the usual ones... but what are you trying to measure here?

Comment: @user42108 My goal in measuring liquidity is to understand how liquid a future contract is compared to the others.

Comment: @demully I'm trying to measure liquidity of future commodity contracts.

Comment: "My goal in measuring liquidity is to understand how liquid a future contract is compared to the others" - different liquidity measures will give you different answers to that question, which is why I asked. In addition, commodity futures are likely to be different and probably more complicated than stocks when it comes to liquidity measurement as they are often traded via calendars or cross-market spreads (e.g. crack, crush...) which are an important source of liquidity.

Comment: @user42108 I'm mostly interested in calendar spread futures and outright futures on commodities. I would like to get a measure of liquidity in terms of readiness to cash conversion. "different liquidity measures will give you different answers to that question" - what are the possible different answers? To which questions they answer? - "probably more complicated than stocks" - Is it only because they are traded as spreads? And, how would I deal with different spreads? Can I measure their liquidity separately?

Comment: "readiness to cash conversion" - meaning selling X lots or $mm ? This seems like 2 questions, 1) how quickly can you execute (e.g. what is your trade as % ADV) and 2) what is the price impact?

Comment: "what are the possible different answers" - an obvious example is quotes vs. trades. Some products are actively quoted but have relatively low volumes and/or OI (e.g. certain FX futures). Others have very little liquidity in the book as it's all - or almost all - hidden. This is why I asked what your goal is - it will determine what you should measure.

Comment: @user42108 I think one way to clarify which liquidity I would like to measure is to say that I want to rank the commodity future spread products by liquidity and by volatility. Then I would like to be able to understand if a product is liquid vs volatile. Ideally that measure of liquidity would be as much as possible opposite to the measure of volatility (anti-correlated). Also, I wanted to understand whether Amihud and Amivest would be appropriate for futures and if the only difference for futures compared to stocks would be their spread months?

Answer (score 1):

The usual measures are trade volumes (from all sources of trades / order books), bid/offer spread, order book depth, quote ages, trade frequency, etc. For quick comparisons, average daily volume is the best (and easy to obtain).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by user42108 in his comment, there are many different contracts for a given commodity. As an example for the energy market, you can have monthly/quarterly or even daily futures (for instance, power at [EEX](https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures)).

Thus a product with a daily delivery can be *liquid*  only nearly the contract expires.

Therefore, you can define the liquidity using the average daily volume in a recent time window as suggested by [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/64207/56820) answer adding some additional constraints/penalty, such as a minimum number of days with at least $N$ trades.

Nevertheless, the time window needed to compute the average volume is strongly dependent on your needs.